# Stellar validator node quorumset not reaching threshold

Tags: stellar-core, validators, quorum

I deployed a full validator node and it was 100% validating for a few months. A few days ago I check it's status on stellar beats and I saw this error `Node not validating: quorum set not reaching threshold`

I changed the quorum set and restated the node but still, it's not validating. Would anybody know what might be wrong?

Quorum set 1:

```
"$sdf_watcher1",
"$sdf_watcher2",
"$sdf_watcher3"
```

Quorum set 2:

```
     [
       {
        "path": "lobster",
        "threshold_percent": 67,
         "validators": [
          "$$lobstr1",
          "$$lobstr2",
          "$$lobstr3",
          "$$lobstr4",
          "$$lobstr5"
        ]
      },
      {
        "path": "sdf",
        "threshold_percent": 67,
        "validators": [
          "$$sdf_watcher1",
          "$$sdf_watcher2",
          "$$sdf_watcher3"
        ]
      },
      {
        "path": "satoshipay",
        "threshold_percent": 67,
        "validators": [
          "$$satoshipay1",
          "$$satoshipay2",
          "$$satoshipay3"
        ]
      },
      {
        "path": "keybase",
        "threshold_percent": 67,
        "validators": [
          "$$keybase1",
          "$$keybase2",
          "$$keybase.io"
         ]
       }
     ]
```

Comment: What's your stellar-core quorum status? => check with `curl localhost:11626/quorum?compact=false` and also a general info with `curl localhost:11626/info`?